# Receive POST DATA from an external site

Tags: angular, post, form-data

I'm posting some form data (`data` & `returnUrl`) from my `angular2` site to an external site. I get redirected there.

I do some process there and external site post `user data` along with `success flag` to the `returnUrl`
[image]

How can I capture this data? I believe `form data` will be posted to server. I have given my `public ip` in `returnUrl`.

Our backend is on Apache server & it's running on Play-Scala. Should I make new `node` application to capture this data or should I follow any other way?

Comment: can you please elloborate and also can you please post what you have tried ?

Comment: I'm posting adhaar & pan details to (https://eiscuat1.camsonline.com/ekycuat3/eKYCVal_Aadhar.aspx) & doing ekyc process there